# how to show one message per day from object array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have an object array with one object for every day (max 30). Each day has meeting details, which I want to show on daily basis.  Hence, How do I traverse through the array to select and display one message per day in order?

The object array is as follows:

```
{
  "meetings": [{
    "date": "07/06/2016",
    "startTime": "15.00",
    "finishTime": "16.00",
    "subject": "local community"
  }, {
    "date": "08/06/2016",
    "startTime": "12.00",
    "finishTime": "12.30",
    "subject": "environment"
  }, {
    "date": "09/06/2016",
    "startTime": "12.00",
    "finishTime": "13.00",
    "subject": "local community"
  }]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "traverse through the array to select and display one message per day in order". Are you trying to show the item that lines up with the current day?

Comment: sorry if not clear... what I meant was that I would like to display the relevant  meeting details for that day only then display the next meetings details on the following day etc.

Comment: So you have the current months data and you want it to display only the current day. Is this an ng-repeat or something? How are they displayed on the dom?

Comment: The data isn't necessarily current months i.e. I could have all of June's meeting details, which I want to display tomorrow on onwards but one meeting per day.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the problem correctly. that you want to only have one message per day even if there are multiple in the array. the easiest way would be to convert it to a map.

if you want to show the last message for a given date then do this

```
var data = { "meetings" : [...]};
var messages = {};
for(var message of data.meetings) {
  messages[message.date] = message;
}
```

if you want to show the first message for a given date then you just have to add an if statement

```
var data = { "meetings" : [...]};
var messages = {};
for(var message of data.meetings) {
  if(!messages[message.date]) {
    messages[message.date] = message;
  }
}
```

**update:**
if you want to preserve the messages you can use a map of arrays

```
var data = { "meetings" : [...]};
var messages = {};
for(var message of data.meetings) {
  if(!messages[message.date]) {
    messages[message.date] = [];
  }
  messages[message.date].push(message);
}
```

you can then find the 7th message (in order of appearance in the array) for a particular day with the following code

```
var message = messages["01/01/2012"][6];
```

Comment: Yes I think understood the issue but I'm not sure what 'convert to map' means and how would I show for example the 7th meeting on a particular day?

Answer (score 0):

app.js (where your JSON file is called meetings.json)

```
var app = angular.module('Meetings', []);

app.factory('meetings', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('meetings.json')
         .success(function(data) {
           return data;
         })
         .error(function(data) {
          console.log("error");
           return data;

         });
}]);


app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'meetings', function($scope, meetings) { 
  meetings.success(function(data){
    $scope.meeting = data;
});
}]);
```

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="day in meeting.meetings">
  <p>{{day.date}}</p>
  <p>{{day.startTime}}</p>
  <p>{{day.finishTime}}</p>
  <p>{{day.subject}}</p>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: Not quite, this would go through the JSON file and display all of meeting details in one go.

Comment: Well, instead of ng-repeat you could use <p>{{meeting.meetings[x].date}}</p> to display the  X+1 meeting's date, where x starts from 0. You can do the same for startTime,finishTime,etc.

Comment: Are you able to do a quick jsfiddle for me please. I think I understand your concept but still not sure how I would increase the x+1 each day to show the next meeting details for the next day.